# WPF MVVM - instantiating a ViewModel from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to MVVM and still learning. I used the article in the link below as an example to implement a simple app with a tabbed workspace that uses two views: "All Customers" and "New Customer".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic

In the example used by the article above, the shell app (MainWindowViewModel) uses a control panel with two buttons: "View all customers" and "Create New Customer". When the user clicks on these buttons, the respective view is open in the tabbed-workspace of the main shell.

My question now is: if we want to add a button "Create New Customer" on the "All Customers" view and when the user clicks on this button, the "New Customer" view opens as a tabbed workspace in the main shell, what would be the best way of doing this?

Do I need to use a messaging service to broadcast/send to all colleagues a "CreateNewCustomer" message, for example, and have the main shell (MainWindowViewModel) register to "CreateNewCustomer" and then its action would be to instantiate the "New Customer" view in its tabbed workspace?

Or is there a better/simpler/more elegant way of doing this? Please note that I am not using Prism, MVVMLight or any other MVVM framework. I am building my own framework as part of my learning.

Many thanks for taking your time to answer my question(s).

Comment: IMO, you can show a dialog window with necessary fields to create a new customer, and add it to customers collection when user of the app presses OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow your description.

You should have a WindowViewmodel.

That maybe has a collection of viewmodels for your tabs. Or if it doesn't, it could do.

WHichever way things work, the usercontrol you are working on will have a button on it and it's a child of the same window you're going to show something else on.

Add a NewUserCommand to WindowViewmodel. This news up and adds NewCustomerViewModel to the collection your tabcontrol is bound to. That templates the tab into a NewCustomerView using viewmodel first.

The remaining problem is how you get from a button which is in a child usercontrol to the window's viewmodel.
You do that by using a relativesource binding.
Which will look something like:

```
{Binding DataContext.NewUserCommand,
  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourWindowType}}}
```

This assumes you're ok with a tabcontrol for your "tabbed workspace".  If you have windows in mind somehow then I recommend reconsidering that.

I would also say that learning wpf is hard enough without picking a framework to make your commands easier. I suggest you take a look at the source code for mvvmlight and relaycommand. There's a lot to it. Messenger is also quite a handy thing to use. I often don't use anything but relaycommand and messenger out mvvmlight btw.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks for help! However, interestingly, if I try the same method to close my workspace, and bind to the ```CloseWorkspaceCommand``` it doesn't work, but it works if I don't use the relativeSource. So, this doesn't work: ```<Button Content="Cancel" Command="{ Binding Path=DataContext.CloseWorkspaceCommand, RelativeSource={ RelativeSource AncestorType={ x:Type vm:MainWindowView } } }"/>``` but this works: ```<Button Content="Cancel" Command="{ Binding Path=CloseWorkspaceCommand }"/>```. Why? And yes I use an observable collection of view models.

Comment: The command is in the datacontext of the button. Which means your button is probably in your window rather than one of the usercontrols in your tabcontrol. If you did what I described above then each tab item has a usercontrol/view in it and it's datacontext is the corresponding viewmodel in an observablecollection bound to it's itemssource. A button outside the tabcontrol and in the window would be in the datacontext of the windowviewmodel instead.

Comment: I've worked it out eventually. The CloseWorkspaceCommand is implemented in a base class of tabbed workspaces and all workspaces inherit from this class. Thus it makes sense that I cannot use a relative path to the data context of my MainWindowViewModel. Thanks again Andy for all your help.